# Trying a date within Tkinter - Python

Tags: python, datetime, if-statement, tkinter, error-handling

After testing out many times and reading Stackoverflow for several hours, I decided to right this question. My Text (part of the bigger code) is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox


def test_click():
  global ipt_dt   
  global coef
  global z
  global w
  z = item_prosp['Accrual_Start'].min()
  w = item_prosp['Accrual_End'].max()
  ipt_d = tkvar_d.get()
  ipt_m = tkvar_m.get()
  ipt_y = tkvar_y.get()  
  x = 0
  while x == 0:
    ipt = str(ipt_d + '/'+ ipt_m + '/' + ipt_y)
    try:
        ipt_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(ipt, "%d/%b/%Y")
        if ipt_dt < z or ipt_dt > w:
                messagebox.showinfo("Error", "The input date is outside scope date") 
    else:
         print("Date ok")
        x =+ 1
    except: 
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "The input date is not valid")
        ipt_d = 0
        ipt_m = 0
        ipt_y = 0
        continue
```

And the tkinter section of the code that generate the inputs is:

```
 #Question 1 - Evaluation date
 label4 = Label(window, text='Please inform the valuation date :', bg='white').grid(row=13, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=2, sticky=W)
 tkvar_d = StringVar(window)
 tkvar_m = StringVar(window)
 tkvar_y = StringVar(window)
 choices_d = ['1', '2', '3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31']
 choices_m = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
 choices_y = ['2018','2019', '2020', '2021','2022','2023','2024','2025','2026','2027','2028','2029','2030']
 popupmenu_d = OptionMenu(window, tkvar_d, *choices_d)
 popupmenu_m = OptionMenu(window, tkvar_m, *choices_m)
 popupmenu_y = OptionMenu(window, tkvar_y, *choices_y)
 label5 = Label(window, text='Day :', bg='white').grid(row=14, column=0, sticky=E+W)
 popupmenu_d.grid(row=15, column=0, padx=2, sticky=E+W)
 label6 = Label(window, text='Month :', bg='white').grid(row=14, column=1, sticky=E+W)
 popupmenu_m.grid(row=15, column=1, padx=2, sticky=E+W)
 label7 = Label(window, text='Year :', bg='white').grid(row=14, column=2, sticky=E+W)
 popupmenu_y.grid(row=15, column=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W)
 Button(window, text="Test Date", width=10, command=test_click).grid(row=15, column=3, padx=5, pady=10, sticky=W)
```

The sample value for W when the file is run is:

```
2018-04-18 00:00:00
```

and for Z is:

```
2018-04-18 00:00:00
```

My need is to import a file (externally built and already structured), read 2 values from it (variables Z and W in the code) and compare it with an input variable (ipt_dt) which is a date filled in by the user through 3 dropdown menus from tkinter.

The error is that the try is not going through the if statement and it never prints out if the input is outside the scope date. Everytime I enter a date smaller than the minimum date or higher than the maximum date it returns the showerror message eventhou it pritns the "Date ok".

Anyone has any idea on how to solve this or why my fi is being ignored?

Thanks!

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with `tkinger`. [Edit] your Question and strip down your code to **only** `def  test_click(...`. Add sample data for `z, w, ipt` as well.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it, I made the changes as suggested.

Comment: If I correct the **indentation errors** and remove the `while ...` it works as expected. Remove also **all** after `.showerror(...`, as this leads to a **infinite loop**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your originally posted code and you load the Excel into a df with the load_click function. But you don't actually run the load_click function anywhere, so the dataframe isn't loaded and so `z` and `w` aren't filled.

If you change the click1() function as follows, then it should work (it did for me with some sample data).

```
def click1():
  global a
  a = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file", filetypes = ( ("Excel file", "*.xlsx"), ("All files", "*.*") ) )
  output1.insert(END, a)
  global a1
  a1 = output1.get() 
  load_click()
```

Or add a seperate 'load' button if you want (at the bottom of the #File1 part):

```
Button(window, text="Load", width=6, command=load_click).grid(row=4, column=3, padx=5, sticky=W)
```

You might also want to add another `x = 1` in the if-statement. Otherwise the messagebox will keep popping up due to the while loop, making it impossible to correct the input date.

```
x = 0
while x == 0:
    ipt = str(ipt_d + '/'+ ipt_m + '/' + ipt_y)
    try:
        ipt_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(ipt, "%d/%b/%Y")
        print type(ipt_dt)
        if (ipt_dt < z) or (ipt_dt > w):
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "The input date is outside scope date")
            x = 1 # I've added this one
        else:
            print("Date ok")
            x =+ 1
    except: 
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "The input date is not valid")
        ipt_d = 0
        ipt_m = 0
        ipt_y = 0
    continue
```

Comment: The type for Z and W is datetime. This is what is the most weird for me. Inputting direct values work perfectly, but when imported through tkinter it does not work. My suspicion lays on importing the df in the same window as I am trying to read it. What you think?